# Table row backgroung color changes when check box is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a script in PHP where the data is coming from mysql db. My requirement is if the checkbox is already checked (data coming from db) the table row color should be a different color, its just to highlight the user that its been checked and attention is required. There should be also be an option if the user unchecks it the background color needs to go off. I have worked on the script and if already checked its showing a red bg color. But when i uncheck it, its not working. Can anyone pls guide me on this. My script is below:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(window).load(function(){
$(function () {
    $('input:checked').parent().css('background-color', '#ff0000');
});
});
</script>

<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[
$(window).load(function(){
$(":checkbox").on("change", function() {
    $(this).parent().toggleClass("checked", this.checked);
});
});//]]> 

</script>
<style type="text/css">
    .checked {
    background-color: #ff0000;
}
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="company">
        <input type="checkbox" name="Selected[]" class="checkboxC" value="8">
             Company 8
</div>
<div class="company">
        <input type="checkbox" name="Selected[]" class="checkboxC" value="9" checked>
             Company 9
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I guess my question is not clear...

Comment: Did you check what is 'this' inside change function and what is "$(this).parent()". Is it giving the desired element you want?

Comment: Iam having a problem with this function only. No its not giving the desired element i want.

Comment: Can you give some working example to debug? Keep the code in a fiddle and update in the question.

Comment: why not use same thing?`$(function() {
    $('input:checked').parent().toggleClass("checked", this.checked);
  });`

Comment: Perfect. Thank you so much @Guradio.

Comment: @SanjuMenon glad to help i will post it as answer so we can close this post ok?

Comment: Yes @guradio. Also pls let me know $(function() { $('input:checked'). How can i change this to a class function that is in input type=checkbox, iam using a class called 'checkboxC'

Comment: `$('input:checkbox.checkboxC')` use `:checkbox` not `:checked` for selecting checkbox to select checked then you can use the old just add `.checkboxC` this is when the checkbox has a class `.checkboxC`

Comment: Its not working. I tried  $('input:checkbox.checkboxC').parent().toggleClass. But not getting the desired output

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112108/discussion-between-guradio-and-sanju-menon).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
$(window).load(function() {
  $(":checkbox").on("change", function() {
    $(this).parent().toggleClass("checked", this.checked);
  });
});
$(window).load(function() {
  $(function() {
    $('input:checked').parent().toggleClass("checked", this.checked);//use .parent().toggleClass("checked", this.checked)
  });
});
```

```css
.checked {
  background-color: #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="company">
  <input type="checkbox" name="Selected[]" class="checkboxC" value="8">Company 8
</div>
<div class="company">
  <input type="checkbox" name="Selected[]" class="checkboxC" value="9" checked>Company 9
</div>
```